# Choose best fitting regex

Tags: python, regex

This may be a strange question but it got me puzzled long enought to ask. For simplicity let say there is a specific part of code, where I must choose function to execute based on given string. Using regex it may look like this:

```
if re.match(string, pattern1):
    foo(string)
elif re.match(string, pattern2):
    bar(string)
```

But it got me thinking. What if string matches both pattern1 and pattern2. Is there a way to determine which pattern better 'fits' the string. For example:

```
www\.(?P<subdmain>[a-z]*)\.(?P<site>[a-z]*)\.com
```

and

```
www\.api\.(?P<site>[a-z]*)\.com
```

both matches url:

```
www.api.awesomesite.com
```

But second one is more specyfic. Is there a way to choose right chunk of code to execute. Note that this is not a problem I can't solve by simply place regexes in right order (and I propably will:)) but those are configured in yaml file and there may be a lot of them. I'm convinced that someone will eventually make a mistake. And I want to save that dumbass a painfull moments (propably future me:)) any suggestions?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611860/determine-regular-expressions-specificity.

Comment: Please provide some more realistic input :)

Comment: @Apero "Similar to the process that Nginx uses to select the server block that will process a request, Nginx also has an established algorithm for deciding which location block within the server to use for handling requests." from article about nginx:) I've downloaded code, but have no time to study yet. I know this is right solution - but I'm just curious:) I have this funny feeling under my skull and I can't scratch myself:)

Comment: @Jan this is my input:)

Comment: I found this: https://docops.ca.com/ca-embedded-entitlements-manager/12-51/en/programming/policy-evaluation/policy-matching/best-match-handling-for-regular-expression-policies

Comment: @Apero You're the best! This may be it:)